# Hole of rational expression: (x-9)/(sqrt(x) - 3)

Tags: rational-functions

> $$(x-9)/(√x - 3)$$

Note that the $3$ of the denominator is not part of the square root (just $x$).

Additionally, the hole of this expression is $(9,6)$. I don't know how to reach this result, aside from the fact that I must first find a common factor between the numerator and denominator.

I've attempted multiplying by $x$, which produces $(x^2-9x)/(x-3x)$, but this doesn't seem to help. Somebody point me in the right direction please.

Comment: $x-9=(\sqrt{x}-3)(\sqrt{x}+3)$

Comment: In my previous answer, I used a difference of two squares. Can that be applied here?

Comment: @randomgirl I would suggest deleting that comment. OP is seemingly doing homework based on a previous question and you shouldn't just hand out answers.

Comment: Multiplying by x/x doesn't even yield that.